# Material UI Input vs. TextField for Read-Only views

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on building out a new Material UI form. I am wondering if there is a preferred component for read-only fields. I am comparing the `Input` and `TextField` component but can't really tell why one would be superior to the other.

Below is a small screenshot of the form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Input Component:

- The Input component is a lower-level component that provides a basic
  input field.
- It is more customizable and can be used for simple input
  scenarios.
- If you need a plain text input without additional features
  like labels, helper text, or adornments, the Input component might be
  a good choice.
  Note: Input & InputBase both pretty similar generic components of MUI. Input comes with borderBottom and InputBase is plain Input with no style.

TextField Component:

- The TextField component is a higher-level component that encapsulates an Input along with additional features like labels, helper text, styling, error massages and so on.
- If you need additional styling, labels, helper text, or other features, the TextField component might be more convenient and you can convert a TextField to select with "select" prop and passing MenuItems.